# Coefficients of factors in terms of those of the product

Tags: polynomials

I have asked this question on Math Stackexchange but received no reply, so I am trying it here.

If we have two polynomials $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, $q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mb_j x^j$, then the coefficients of the product $p(x)q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}c_kx^k$ are given by 
$c_k=\sum_{i=0}^ka_ib_{k-i}$ (where we take $a_i=0=b_j$ for $i,j<0$, $i>n$, $j>m$). Consider the expression for the $c_k$ as a system of $n+m+1$ (non-linear) equations in the $n+m+2$ variables  $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_m$. What is known about solving this system? In other words, can we express the coefficients $a_i, b_j$ in terms of the $c_k$'s? I think this is not possible in full generality. I could not find anything useful except for the simplest cases, such as $n=1=m$. But I would be interested in special cases, partial results, etc.

Comment: Hi, the question is not of the research level, but considering you didn't get an answer on stackexchange I gonna answer it reel quick before it is closed.

So, the questions could be (1) are there any solutions to this system and (2) how does one find these solutions;

(1) is easy over $\mathbb{C}$: any polynomial factorizes into the product over its roots $a_n \prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)$, and your factors are some products of this decomposition. Over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example, this problem is much harder - polynomials which do not admit non-trivial decompositions are called irreducible.

Comment: (2) Is harder (and it actually depends on what do you expect as expression). Closed formula for this kind of things is more or less as hard as closed formula for roots, and as you probably know there is no closed formula in radicals for deg > 5. 

Checking irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ is possible, you can google it if this is the thing you were interested.